# How to read the hints in SQL Server Management Studio execution plan

Tags: sql-server-2008, indexing, ssms, sql-execution-plan

I am having difficulties understanding the hints in the execution plan you can get through SQL Server Management Studio. Here is an example (simplified, but everything is included)

[image]

> **Index Seek (NonClustered)**
>
> **Predicate**
>
> PROBE([Bitmap1047], ScheduleId)
>
> **Object**
>
> IX_Date
>
> **Output list**
>
> ScheduleId Date
>
> **Seek Predicates**
>
> Date >= ‘2012-01-02’ Date < (‘2012-05-14’)

- ScheduleId is a guid based foreign key.
- IX_Date is an index with Date, ScheduleId and INCLUDE Hours

To me the above looks pretty good. Index Seek should be good. It hits a relevant index. However, this item takes a very large portion of the execution time (otherwise I wouldn't bother trying to understand it). That puzzles me and I suspect it is because there is something basic that I do not understand, when reading this.

Can anyone shine some light on it for me?

Comment: What is the "Actual Number of Rows" and "Estimated Row Size" returned from the Index Seek?

Comment: I updated the question to include this information.

Comment: Can you post the full query plan?

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks, but I'm afraid I don't have the query plan directly available any longer, it is a long time ago. But the question is also more about how to read it than analyzing the specific issue.

Comment: Here, only the date part of the query can be used in the index seek, the PROBE(...) condition is applied on all rows matching the date part. see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/07/07/652668.aspx for a good article about column orders in multi column indices for a good hint. May not be usable here, as I don't know if the PROBE-Statement is an equality comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything that looks too strange from the data you've provided.  The cost of the non-clustered index seek is only 12% on this plan, so unless there are a lot of other operations that are taking a trivial amount of time and this operation is relatively large it looks okay to me.

I think the execution cost may seem high because it's doing the non-clustered index seek across half a million rows.

Comment: This operation is there 5 times and takes 12% each, so that's why I'm looking at it as the main culprit. Can I prevent it from doing index seek among that many rows with an index of some sort?

Comment: That does sound like a problme.  If the seek is the same in each of the five cases you could possibly write the query differently so the seek is only performed once.  Would it be possible to post the query itself?

Comment: The query is auto generated from Entity Framework. I know that I can rewrite the query, but as I cannot easily do that, that's why I, with this ticket, am trying to focus on reading the Execution Plan an optimizing based on what I already have.

Comment: I see.  It may be possible to use a slightly different Linq query to generate the same data using a better execution plan.  You might also be be able to slightly alter your entities and relationships to generate a better query.  The last alternative would be to put the query in a stored procedure, but that defeats the purpose of Entity Framework.

Comment: Are you using EF4 or newer?  You might try upgrading to the newest version to see if it generates better SQL code for your entities.

Comment: That may work, however my focus with this question is to learn better how to read the hints from the execution plan.